# Semicolon gets added by langchain/openai

Tags: openai-api, langchain

```
sql = "UPDATE users SET name='prasad' where id = 90 UPDATE users SET name = 'john' where id = 88;"
chat_model = ChatOpenAI(
    model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    temperature=0.0,
    verbose=True,
    cache=False,
)

messages = [
    SystemMessage(
        content=
        """
        how many semicolon given by user in the following sql query?
        """
    ),
    SystemMessage(content=sql)
]

result = chat_model.invoke(messages)
print(result.content)
```

There is only one semicolon given in sql file but openAI detects its two. When I print those sql through openAI, i found that ; getting added automatically.

I want to get count of semicolon added in the sqls`

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using OpenAI to check for this when you can probably write a simple program to count how many semicolons there are? If anything, use your own code would probably be faster than querying OpenAI.

Comment: @LHY Thanks for your response.

Use case is user will submit SQL file with mutliple SQL queries.
I want to check everything like syntax, incorrect / missing keywords, missing semicolon at the end of SQL